# Is it permitted to be upset after your favourite soccer team lost an important match?

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, mussar-ethics, sport-athletics, performance-entertainment, parashat-shelach

I have a friend who is extremely into international sports games. When the team that he supports loses an important game, he gets really upset. When his team recently got kicked out of the competition, I caught him almost crying. Now whatever his particular predilections are, why is this not forbidden? Should it not go under

> You cried a futile crying and so I will give you something to cry
>   about

that Hashem told the Jews when they cried regarding the spies?

Comment: I have nothing against the question, but I think it would be appropriate to specify whether or not you are the same person who asked it here: http://www.needaneitzah.com/questions/20/is-it-permitted-to-be-upset-after-your-favourite-soccer-team-lost-an-important-match This way no one suspects you of plagiarism. Once you do so you'll get my +1.

Comment: @DovF what goes around comes around

Comment: why the downvote?

Comment: @Yehuda I don't understand what you mean. (I'm not criticizing, and FYI I'm not the one who downvoted.)

Comment: @DovF i didnt think it was you, btw I had permission to do bring the question here!

Comment: @Yehuda Ah, I see. I still suggest writing that you had permission in the actual question, so that no one (who doesn't read the comments) walks away thinking the wrong thing (or maybe just write "originally asked here" with a link). Just a thought.

Comment: Per http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/76/2, I agree with @DovF. If you're copying someone else's work with permission, please indicate as much. If it's without permission, please replace your copying with something in your own words.

Comment: Also, you could improve this question by citing and providing more context for the quotation.

Comment: I didn't know that sadness was something we held halakha about.

Comment: Yehuda, You're still missing a note about whether you've copied this material with permission of the author.

Comment: @Yehuda You've got my +1 (though Isaac Moses still has a point - sorry for nitpicking).

Comment: @DovF no worries, you were right!

Comment: @IssacMoses Thanks for the tip, updated it now!

Comment: @CharlesKoppelman Orach Chaim 1:3, everyone has to be sad about the churban

Comment: Is there any reason that this question is limited specifically to sports teams and not anything else that someone may have cause to become upset about? (e.g. "Is it permitted to be upset when you get stuck in traffic?", "Is it permitted to be upset when there is a hole in your sock?", "Is it permitted to be upset when the store is out of your favorite flavor of jam?"...)

Comment: @jake of course, Hashem expects you to become upset at those things, in fact they are probably a punishment. However here you are not supposed to be upset!

Comment: @Yehuda, The difference being...?

Comment: @Yehuda - Your futile crying idea reminds me of a Pasuk in Sefer Devarim: “Tachat asher lo avadta et Hashem Elohecha b'simcha uvetuv levav" ... If we are not happy when we serve Hashem, then Hashem will make us unhappy in our service of the Sitra Achra.

Comment: @ba - That does not apply anymore, since the *churban* (i.e., the state of destruction in which lies our Holy Temple) is becoming less and less significant. It will be rebuilt soon and quickly, so people are coming to their senses and rejoicing about its eminent forthcoming rather than being depressed about the previous times that it has been destroyed. (Cf: http://www.chabadtalk.com/forum/showpost.php3?p=41266&postcount=14 ... According to this, Hashem does not want us to cry anymore, rather He desires that we be happy. Let's not take mourning so seriously and instead be *marbeh b'simchah*.)

Comment: @AdamMosheh It was still relevant in the times of all the nos'ey keilim on the Shulchan Aruch, because no one disputes that... (That post quotes the Rebbe, but I have not seen that in his name before and it brings no source)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the question is the phrase "crying for *chinam*". My suspicion is it's not "you cried about something unimportant", rather it's "you cried when there was every reason not to."

G-d had promised them they'd enter the land, and here they were crying "oh boo hoo we won't enter the land", there was no reason for them to be sad.

Whereas if my favorite team loses, well I feel upset. That's not a sign of diminished faith of any sort, G-d hadn't promised me my team would win.

There's likely some measure of good sense of proportion, *how* upset should a sports game make me (and how much should(n't) it allow me to reduce my normal performance of service to G-d), but I think applying the comment from the Spies is quite extreme.

Note the conversation between G-d and Jonah at the end of his book; Jonah's upset is a teaching moment, not a cause for punishment:

**"Jonah, are you really that upset over a silly gourd?"**

*"Yes G-d, so upset I wish I was dead."*

**Ah-hah! Now you understand why I don't want the metropolis of Ninveh to die.**

Comment: Excellent reference to [Yonah](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt1704.htm).

Comment: Terrific answer! +1

Comment: +1 for the _Yona_ reference, but I'm not convinced your translation/interpretation of _chinam_ is correct.

Comment: From now on, whenever someone gets upset over something insignificant, I'm going to say to them, "?הַהֵיטֵב חָרָה-לְךָ עַל-הַקִּיקָיוֹן"

Comment: Nice answer! I like it!

Answer (score 1):

It's not forbidden because anything that is not explicitly forbidden is permitted.  What source holds that this is forbidden?

Comment: Note the question is tagged [tag:hashkafah-philosophy] rather than [tag:halacha]. While the question ("why is this not forbidden") sounds like it's asking about _halacha_, I doubt that that was actually the asker's intent. +1, though.